# summing up column values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table "fruits" with the following data

```
id  a 
123 apple
223 orange
646 apple
757 banana
876 kiwi
989 orange
```

I would like to write a mysql that would sum up the occurences of column "a" and puts them into 3 separate buckets: one for apple, one for oranges and the rest under "others"

```
SELECT 
     count(*) as total
     sum(if(a = 'apple',1,0)) as applecount
     , sum(if(a = 'orange',1,0)) as orangecount
     , sum(`applecount` + `orangecount` - total) as others

FROM fruits
```

But on running the query, gives the following error
Unknown column "applecount" in field list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) as total,
       sum(a = 'apple') as applecount,
       sum(a = 'orange') as orangecount,
       sum(a not in ('orange', 'apple')) as others
FROM fruits
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2270a/1)

Comment: [Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a `WHERE` clause. This restriction is imposed because when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/problems-with-alias.html)  See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2270a/5/0).

Comment: No worries.  They can, of course, be used post-evaluation in `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` clauses.